# Showing that a matrix equation is also satisfied by the transpose matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I want to prove the following statement:

> If a matrix L satisfies $L^T \eta L = \eta$ then the transpose matrix
>   $L^T$ also satisfies the same equation.

When I try to solve this, I always end up with the equation $L \eta L^T=\eta$ which seems to be correct only if $L=L^T$ which I think is not the case in general. So my question is: **How can I prove this statement in a proper way?**

---

***NOTE:*** The matrix $\eta$ satisfies $\eta^T = \eta$ and its inverse is also equal to itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "its inverse is equal to itself"? I mean, if $\eta^{-1} = \eta$, then this is simple: From what you have it follows that $\eta^{-1}L^T\eta L = I$, so $(\eta L)^{-1} = \eta^{-1}L^T$. This implies $\eta L\eta^{-1}L^T = I$. Since $\eta^{-1}= \eta$, you have $L\eta L^T = \eta$.

Comment: If $\eta$ is only assumed to be invertible, then the claim holds if $L$ is normal. This follows from the fact that the Frobenius adjoint of the linear map $AX := L^TXL$ is $A^*X = LXL^T$, and that $A$ is normal if $L$ is so.

Comment: Notice that if $\eta$ is the identity, $L$ is orthogonal. There are non symmetric orthogonal matrices.

Comment: In your first comment you found the same thing as me. I mean if $L^T \eta L = \eta$ then it can be shown that $L \eta L^T = \eta$. But what I want to show is $(L^T)^T \eta L^T = \eta$. And we know two things about the $\eta$ matrix; $\eta^T = \eta$, $\eta^{-1} = \eta$. This statement is taken from a physics book so I think the mathematical terminology in your second comment is way too advanced to prove the statement for an undergraduate physics student. So I am looking for a more simple proof by using only the basic linear algebra knowledge in transpose and inverse matrices.

Comment: @sahin: $(L^T)^T = L$ for **every** matrix $L$.

Comment: @sahin In my first comment I proved $(L^T)^T\eta L^T = \eta$ only under the condition that $\eta^{-1} = \eta$.

Comment: So sorry, I don't know how I missed that. I already solved the question in the beginning but was not able to see I solved it. What a shame. Sorry for taking your time by doing such a mistake.

Comment: @sahin No problem.

Comment: @user251257 You made a mistake in your last equality. ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: oh yes. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a slightly different solution and some comments:

Since $\eta$ is assume to be invertible, $L$ is also invertible. Thus, we have
$$ \eta = \eta^{-1} = L^{-1}\eta^{-1} L^{-T} = L^{-1}\eta L^{-T}, $$
that is
$$ L \eta L^T = \eta. $$

**Notes:**

1. $L$ is not uniquely determined by $\eta$ (nor vice versa $\eta$ is an eigen"vector" of $X\mapsto L^T XL$ w.r.t. eigenvalue $1$).
2. Also notice, $L$ needs not to be symmetric, not even normal. Consider the example
   $$L = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{2} & -1 \\ 1 & -\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix} 
   \qquad\text{and}\qquad
   \eta = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}. $$
   We have
   $$ L^T \eta L = \eta $$
   but
   $$ LL^T = \begin{bmatrix} * & 2\sqrt{2} \\ * & * \end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} * & -2\sqrt{2} \\ * & * \end{bmatrix} = L^T L. $$